# Starting a Tomcat 8.5 localhost through C++? What is the best practice?

Tags: c++, tomcat, tomcat8

I am attempting to create a small C++ Visual Studio Forms (via CPPCLR_WinformsProjekt) application that is essentially a browser but it also starts a local Tomcat 8.5 server with a WAR file in its web apps folder and redirects you to the localhost page. I am working on Windows.

My question precisely is - what is the best way to start the Tomcat server through C++ libraries?

Edit: The way I started solving this is by simply having the tomcat folder with the WAR file zipped within the Visual Studio project. On execution, the file gets unzipped, and I am thinking of having a `system(*start tomcat command*)`.

NB: I know I can start Tomcat through the cmd but I need to get it working via C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I am assuming you are under Windows, but on Unix-es similar ways are available.]

In a C++ program you can execute all commands that a shell can, so the easiest way to start Tomcat would be to use [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) to execute [catalina.bat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) (or `startup.bat`). The is also the most easily configurable way: a user can adapt `setenv.bat` to its needs.

Of course, if you want to omit the `*.bat` files you can:

- either instantiate a JVM using `java.exe` with the appropriate parameters: you need at least `bin/bootstrap.jar` in the system classpath (and usually `bin/tomcat-juli.jar`) and call the main method of `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap` with a parameter of `start`.
- or instantiate a JVM using `jvm.dll` through the [Invocation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) in a similar way as [it is done by `procrun`](https://github.com/apache/commons-daemon/blob/6e47d3fca3e5b131d5d180d9b5caba88ff21c877/src/native/windows/src/javajni.c#L401).

I don't believe these methods give you any advantage over the `*.bat` scripts. To stop a modern Tomcat just send the kill signal.

**Edit:** If you plan to start only one specific web application a full-fledged Tomcat might be overkill. You might instead:

- either use [Tomcat Embedded](https://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-embed-tomcat-server-into-java-web-applications), which boils up to writing on class and calling its `main` method instead of `Boostrap#start`. The advantage is, you just need to distribute a bunch of jar files and your WAR and you don't need a traditional Tomcat installation directory structure,
- or user use [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The way I started solving this is by simply having the tomcat folder with the WAR file zipped within the Visual Studio project. On execution, the file gets unzipped, and I am thinking of having a `system(*start tomcat command*)`. Perhaps I can have a *.bat file as means of executing the server.

Comment: If you just need to execute one WAR you can use Tomcat Embedded and instead of the entire tomcat folder you can get away with a couple of jars (cf. edited answer). If you can modify the WAR and don't mind extra Spring dependencies, you can use Spring Boot.